# Union probability

Tags: r, union, probability

Hello im having some issue with coding union probability in R as i am quite new to the language

```
p(a) = 0.30
p(b)=0.45
p(c)= .40
```

I am trying to find the `p(at least one of three items have been purchased)` which is `p(AuBuC)`

ive tried using dbinom but have recently learned that it only works when all three have the some probability

union(A,B) doesn't seem to work either:

```
 A=0.30
> B=0.45
> C=0.40
> union(A,B,C)
```

> Error in union(A, B, C) : unused argument (C)

any ideas, tips or pointers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If `a`, `b` and `c` are mutual independent, you can try

```
1-prod(1-c(pa,pb,pc))
```

Comment: thank you thomas for taking the time to answer

i calculated this by hand P(AuBuC) and the answer i got was 0.65 while the code above gave me 0.769

am i missing something in the code?

Comment: @alfredandretti What calculation did you do "by hand"? It should be `1-(1 - 0.3)*(1 - 0.45)*(1 - 0.4)` which comes out the same answer as above. If you need help with statistical concepts and probabilities, you should ask for help at [stats.se]. There's nothing really special about R that does the statistics for you. R is basically just a fancy calculator.